# Does the graph of $\ln(-2 - |x|)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, graphing-functions

I tried to figure out if this graph exists, but I don't know if I am thinking this right. The absolute value of $x$ is always positive and the minus in front of the absolute value of $x$ makes it always negative. So my final conclusion is that it does not exist but I am not sure of this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the logarithm of a complex number?

Comment: Yes but I'm just working with the real numbers in this case.

Comment: To be picky, the graph exists, but is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only real numbers you're working with, then no. If you're familiar with complex logarithms then $\log(z)=\log|z|+\mathrm{i}\theta$ might help, where $\theta$ is the argument of $z$.